# Find images not used or override +imageNamed: to log images not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am developing an iOS application with many images. because i have a designer on my side every moment i am using many images that i don't need anymore.

So at the moment, to clean up this mess i was thinking: If i use a category of `UIImage` can i override the `+imageNamed:` to log the name of the image and maybe the method that called it?

something like this:

```
@implementation UIImage (FindImage)

+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name {
  UIImage *img = [self imageNamed:name];

  if (img) {
    return img;
  } else {
    NSLog(@"\n\nImage not found: %@\n\n", name);
    return nil;
  }
}

@end
```

I want to override imageNamed because:

1. I am using it in many different classes
2. I believe that when a xib load an image it call this method

on resume, my question is: `Can i log all images that could not be found on bundle?`

**EDIT**

Refining my question:

i see my question is a little bit complicated so i`m going to try elucidate it.

I want to find all images that my app tries to use, but in my project this images are not found.
I can remove all images, i can create a subclass, i can create categories, i really don't care. Maybe there is a flag on Xcode to complain about missing images...

all i want is to find all places where i`m using an image an this image is not found on bundle.

Comment: NO, NO, NO.  Don't _ever_ override methods in categories.  It's bad mojo.  Subclass, always.

Comment: i know that, what i want to accomplish is find missing images, if you know a better way i`ll be happy to use. I`m asking here because i can't think of anything else.

Comment: Swizzle? http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use https://github.com/steipete/Aspects to inject a logging instruction to the end of  +imageNamed: